# UL LI Selector - Why does this repeat several times with one press and does not function as expected?

Tags: javascript

When I kick start this function with one on key up, it repeats itself several times, and basically just does not work as expected.

**What is expected?**

For the handler to recognise my ul list and allow users to move up and down with a keyboard between li elements. Basically it forms part of an auto-complete function that I am working on, the list always brings the top 5 results depending on what the user inputs (data from php file via snippet of ajax/http request code).

Does anyone have any ideas on what it could be?

```
document.getElementById("whatCountry").onkeyup = function () {
    showHint(this.value);
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handler);
    document.addEventListener("mouseover", handler);
    var active = document.querySelector(".hover") || document.querySelector(".the_results li");

    function handler(e) {
        if (e.which == 40) {
            if (document.getElementById("these_results")) {
                active.classList.remove("hover");
                if (e.which == 40) {
                    active = active.nextElementSibling || active;
                    //alert("something");
                    //document.getElementById("whatCountry").value= active.innerHTML;
                } else if (e.which == 38) {
                    active = active.previousElementSibling || active;
                    //alert("something else");
                    //document.getElementById("whatCountry").value= active.innerHTML;
                } else if (e.which == 9) {
                    //alert("you pressed tab");
                } else if (e.which == 13) {
                    //alert("you pressed enter");
                } else {
                    active = e.target;
                    //alert("exactly whatelse could happen");
                };
                active.classList.add("hover");
            }
        } else {
            alert("The id is not existing so nothing should happen");
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: "does not work as expected." Can you clarify what is expected, even if it seems obvious to you?

Comment: And please, for the love of all of us - look at your formatting before posting.  Qantas 94 Heavy was kind enough to clean up your mess, but it was impossible to read.

Comment: Actually @popnoodles it's not obvious to me at all..in fact I have no idea what I am doing at all, and (perhaps ignorantly) expect everyone on here to know far more than me. The idea is for the value of each list element to be focused on with up and down key functionality (along with css to change to show each being highlighted).

Comment: Very good point @ScottMermelstein, I copied and pasted the code and expected it to look as beautiful on here (as it does on my file), but obviously not. I had spent several hours on this, and posted this question just before closing my laptop down (before the temptation of smashing it against the wall took over!). :/

Comment: Thank you @qantas94heavy for cleaning my code.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to move `handler` and these event listeners outside of the `onkeyup` listener.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", handler);
document.addEventListener("mouseover", handler);
```